# Cron jobs don't get updated after deploying a new version

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

The problem is that I try to delete, or update the cron job and nothing gets updated on the google side.

`gcloud app deploy cron.yaml` - I sent an empty file with only `cron:` in there, and it still displays old cron jobs.

I then tried to update the cron jobs to new settings, and it still displays old information.

Either the documentation doesn't give you the correct directions how to manage cronjobs or I must be doing something extremely wrong.

#### Solution

Needed to specify the project to deploy to: `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml --project=my-project`

Comment: Maybe your gcloud tool isn't configured with the correct project. Run `gcloud config set project your_project_name` and try again.

Comment: That was precisely the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to specify the project to deploy to: `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml --project=my-project`